# ABAP 7.4 way of filling one itab from another?

Tags: abap, internal-tables

Consider, I have `GT_KUNNR` internal table like below:

| KUNNR | TEXT |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | demo text |
| 456 | test inv |

I have second GT_TEXT internal like below:

| KUNNR | TEXT | EXPIRED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | welcome | X |

I am writing the code till now in ABAP as:

```
LOOP AT GT_KUNNR ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<lfs_kunnr>).
  READ TABLE GT_TEXT ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(lfs_text>) WITH KEY kunnr = <lfs_kunnr>-kunnr BINARY SEARCH.
  IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
    <lfs_kunnr>-text = <lfs_text>-text.
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```

My question is, how to achieve above using ABAP 7.4 and upwards? My understanding is, constructor expression (VALUE,FOR,REDUCE..) creates a new type, which I don't need (basically, `GT_KUNNR` is being updated and can have huge records. So, creating new structure/type and then passing that again to `GT_KUNNR` will be a performance bottleneck). So, how to achieve that? Any efficient way?

Comment: It's a myth. I don't know why people think that any code needs to be re-written with some new "ABAP 7.4" syntax. The ABAP 7.4 syntax doesn't replace everything, that's just new syntax which may or may not be used. There is new syntax in every ABAP version. Field symbols have no specific replacement in 7.4, and not later (NB data references have been a possible alternative for a long time, but it's not more efficient). FYI, the constructor expressions don't "create a new type", they are just a new way to fill **variables**.

Comment: Hi @SandraRossi: Thanks for the guided direction and yes, you are right, I should have been asked in much better sense in terms of syntax. Will surely take this into consideration in coming future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this with a constructor operator, then you can use the [CORRESPONDING-operator with a lookup table](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/abencorresponding_constr_using.htm).

But note that this requires that the linking condition between the two tables (`kunnr = kunnr`) uses a table key in the lookup table. That means that the lookup table (in this case `gt_text`) has to be a `SORTED TABLE` or a `HASHED TABLE` with `kunnr` as the keyfield, or that it at least has a `SECONDARY KEY` that matches the condition.

```
" Declarations:
TYPES:
  BEGIN OF kunnr_struct,
    kunnr TYPE kunnr,
    text TYPE string,
  END OF kunnr_struct,
  kunnr_tbl TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF kunnr_struct WITH DEFAULT KEY,
  BEGIN OF text_struct,
    kunnr TYPE kunnr,
    text TYPE string,
    expired TYPE abap_bool,
  END OF text_struct,
  text_tbl TYPE HASHED TABLE OF text_struct WITH UNIQUE KEY kunnr. " <- Important!

" Test data:
DATA(gt_kunnr) = VALUE kunnr_tbl(
   ( kunnr = '123' text = 'demo text'  )
   ( kunnr = '456' text = 'text inv')
).

DATA(gt_text) = VALUE text_tbl(
   ( kunnr = '123' text = 'welcome' expired = abap_true )
).

" The actual code you asked for:

gt_kunnr = CORRESPONDING kunnr_tbl(
    gt_kunnr FROM gt_text USING kunnr = kunnr ).
```

---

> My understanding is, constructor expression (VALUE,FOR,REDUCE..) creates a new type, which I don't need (basically, GT_KUNNR is being updated and can have huge records.

This does not create a new *type*, but according to the documentation I linked above, it does indeed create an interim table with the results in memory. This is unlikely to be a performance problem (the runtime increase would probably be linear at worst), but it could double the memory being used, so it could become a memory problem with very large datasets.

If that is a concern for your use-case, then you can keep using your variant with a loop. If you don't want to use field-symbols, then you can do what many modern ABAP styleguides, [like this one from SAP themselves](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/abencorresponding_constr_using.htm), recommend to use references instead of field-symbols whenever possible. The code from the question using references would look like this:

```
LOOP AT gt_kunnr REFERENCE INTO DATA(lrs_kunnr).
  READ TABLE gt_text REFERENCE INTO DATA(lrs_text) WITH KEY kunnr = lrs_kunnr->kunnr BINARY SEARCH.
  IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
    lrs_kunnr->text = lrs_text->text.
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Hi @philipp : Thanks for this detailed beautiful answer. I tried with this REFERENCE INTO, and it did the job...Let me check the earlier CORRESPONDING one will revert back.